# JQUERY Chamar função com condição

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Atualmente tenho uma função em jquery a chamar o meu controller para carregamento de dados repartidos com base no scroll.

```
var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("ProjectDataList")';
$(window).scroll(scrollHandler);
```

Acontece que gostaria que esta função só fosse chamada (scroll) com uma condição das seguintes entradas:

```
@Html.TextBox("searchString", ViewBag.testData as string, new { @class = "form-control mr-sm-2 ", id = "procurar", @placeholder = "Procurar", style = "width: 300px;", value = "searchString" })               
@Html.CheckBox("checkAcess", new { style = "width: 13px; height: 13px" })
@Html.DropDownList("startStatus", "Todos")
```

A exemplo o checkAcess diferente de false.

tentei algo assim mas sem resultado:

```
if($("#checkAcess") != false){
    var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("ProjectDataList")';
    $(window).scroll(scrollHandler);
}
```

Obrigado por qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tente verificar se o checkbok está selecionado:

```
if($("#checkAcess").is(":checked") === true){
    var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("ProjectDataList")';
    $(window).scroll(scrollHandler);
}
```